# В конце функции появляется какое-то число

Tags: c++, функции

Я написал функцию которая должна выводить все чётные числа до *n*. Функция работает, но в конце само по себе какое-то число появляется.

```
int func(int n){
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
 if(i%2==0)
  cout<<i<<endl;}
 int main(){
   int n=8;
   func(n); 
   return 0;}
```

Выводятся числа `2;4;6;8`, a в конце `3508944`, которая нигде не была написана

Comment: `cout<<func(n);` заменить на `func(n);`. `int func` заменить на `void func`.

Comment: Ничего личного, просто вспомнилось "училка пор математике совсем оборзела - сказала, что я ничего не знаю, и написала в дневник какое-то число"...

Answer (score 2):

Вы просите вывести число, которое возвращает `func()`.

И что она возвращает?

А ничего! Вы не написали `return`. [По стандарту это - неопределенное поведение](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#4), вот компилятор и просто вернул какую-то ерунду.

А если посмотреть на строку

```
n=8;
```

то такой код просто [не должен компилироваться](https://ideone.com/Azvjmh). Что такое `n`? Его объявления нет...

И еще - а зачем вы вообще пытаетесь вывести это `f(n)`? Почему не просто вызвать?

Comment: Выход из не-void функции без return = UB.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну, в VC++  это ошибка C4716... Возможно, VC++ не соответствует стандарту, спорить не стану. Не дадите ссылку на стандарт, чтоб я ответ изменил?

Comment: Сейчас поищу...

Comment: Откопал: http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#4

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо!